# How can I retrieve data from database which are updated in instant date? I want to retrieve only those data which are updated today(12 am to 12pm)

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve data from database which are updated in instant date? I want to retrieve only those data which are updated today (12 am to 12 pm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a column where you keep the update timestamp, and use that timestamp in your query.